# A question involving the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

If $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$, show that there exist distinct $c_1,c_2\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c_1)+f'(c_2)=2$.

I was trying to use the MVT, but I cannot think how to apply it for two numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By MVT, there is $c_1\in (a,(a+b)/2)$ such that
$$\frac{f((a+b)/2)-f(a)}{(b-a)/2}=f'(c_1).$$
In the same way there is $c_2\in ((a+b)/2,b)$ such that
$$\frac{f(b)-f((a+b)/2)}{(b-a)/2}=f'(c_2).$$
Finally add the two equations and use $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$:
$$2=\frac{f((a+b)/2)-a}{(b-a)/2}+\frac{b-f((a+b)/2)}{(b-a)/2}=f'(c_1)+f'(c_2).$$
Note that $c_1\not=c_2$ because $c_1<(a+b)/2<c_2$.